# Readonly Domain Controller for Remote Office

Tags: domain-controller, rodc

We have two locations, one in Miami (192.168.3.0/24) and the other in New York (192.168.5.0/24). The two locations are linked via VPN. I wanted to set up an Read-only Domain Controller (RODC) in New York, with servers and PCs running in that location using that DC for DNS and Authentication.

I've come across the following RODC tutorial from Microsoft:

https://tech.iot-it.no/microsoft/microsoft-windows-rodc-setup/

To achieve what I am looking for (i.e. DNS and authentication) in the remote office, do I really need to create a new Site and DNS Zone?

Is there a more simplified configuration for my needs?

Comment: AFAIK the more simplified configuration is a normal, rather than a read-only DC in your NY location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set up a new site with your subnet? Yes, you should.

Do you need to set up a new rDNS zone for your subnet? You don't need to, but I consider it best practice.